# Open itunes window inside ios cordova application

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, cordova-plugins

i`m using [apache cordova](https://cordova.apache.org) to build ios applications from some html, css and js. At this time i need to open other application inside opened application, for this purposes i use [startapp](https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp) plugin. Everything is ok, but i want opening itunes window inside app with link on application that need to open if application not installed. Here is function that i wrote, but it not give me the result that i want:

```
function appToApp(identifier, iTunesUrl, success, fail) {
    var app;

    // Init app starter
    if(device.platform === 'iOS') {
        app = startApp.set(identifier);
    } else if(device.platform === 'Android') {
        app = startApp.set({
            "package": identifier
        });
    }


    console.log('Checking ' + identifier + ' application existence...');
    app.check(function(values) {
        console.log('ok, application installed!');
        console.log(values);

        // Run application
        console.log('Running ' + identifier + ' application...');

        // Start application
        app.start(function() {
            console.log('App with identifier = ' + identifier + ' opened!');
            if (typeof(success) == 'function') {
                success.call();
            }
        }, function(error) {
            console.log('Can not open app with identifier = ' + identifier + '!');
            if (typeof(fail) == 'function') {
                fail.call();
            }
            console.warn(error);
        });

    }, function(error) {
        console.warn('Something wrong with application, checking failed!');

        // Open iTunes
        var iTunes = startApp.set('itunes://');
        iTunes.start(function() {
            console.log('iTunes opened!');
        }, function(error) {
            console.warn('Can not open iTunes!');
        });


        console.warn(error);
    });

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any logs? What exactly doesn't work

Comment: Hi, i have my own logs that i define in code with console.log. I intentionally try to open not installed app. Here logs:
- Checking app:// application existense
- Something wrong with application, checking failed
- Can not open itunes

Comment: "What exactly doesn't work" - plugin can`t open itunes inside other application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result i have used this cordova plugins [Custom-URL-scheme](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme), [AppAvailability](https://github.com/ohh2ahh/AppAvailability).

First of all i attached custom scheme to app that need launch form another app:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-customurlscheme --variable URL_SCHEME=mycoolapp
```

Function that open app:

```
/**
 * Run app from other app
 * Dependencies:
 * https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme
 * https://github.com/ohh2ahh/AppAvailability
 *
 * @param {string} scheme - scheme part of url
 * @param {string} url - custom application url
 * @param {string} iTunesUrl - url on application that located on iTunes
 */
function appToApp(scheme, url, iTunesUrl) {
    appAvailability.check(
        // URI Scheme or Package Name
        scheme,
        function() {
            // Success callback
            console.log(scheme + ' is available :)');
            // Open application
            window.open(url, '_system');
        },
        function() {
            // Error callback
            console.log(scheme + ' is not available :(');

            if (iTunesUrl) {
                console.log('Installing app from iTunes');
                window.open(iTunesUrl, '_system');
            } else {
                alert("Application " + scheme +  " is not available on this device, please install application first");
            }
        }
    );
}
```